# как увеличить счетчик через функцию

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Глупый конечно вопрос но все же...

```
    let cs = 100;
    // const [count, setCount] = useState(100)
    const [items, setItems] = useState([
         alls('one'),
         alls('then'),
         alls('this'),
    ]);

    function alls(text){
        return {
            text,
            id: cs++,
        }
    }
    const item = () => {
        const newItem = alls('text')
        setItems((items) => [...items, newItem])
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

функция item запускается по кнопке.
Подскажите пожалуйста. как увеличить счётчик что бы id увеличился... заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам надо написать так:

```
const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    alls('one', 100),
    alls('then', 101),
    alls('this', 102)
  ]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(103);

  function alls(text: string, id: number) {
    return {
      text,
      id,
    };
  }

  const item = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);

    const newItem = alls('text', count);
    
    setItems((items) => [...items, newItem]);
  };

  console.log(items);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <p>123</p>
      <button onClick={item}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Так я тоже пробовал, он зацикливает и отключается

Comment: Можете пожалуйста опубликовать минимальный рабочий код, где-то публично, чтобы можно было поэксперементировать. Т.к. только в этом участке кода (по крайней мере) я не вижу ничего такого из-за чего что-то зацикливалось бы

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-defrxx?file=index.tsx в консоле

Comment: @Moroshka Попробуйте так, у меня сработало

Comment: К сожалению нет, он не прибавляет + 1).... что для меня тоже очень странно

Comment: @Moroshka маловероятно, но может вы не то скопировали?) Потому что я перезапускаю который раз и он прибавляет единицу как для начальных данных так и для последующих

Comment: вроде все верно https://ibb.co/s5MHWzc

Comment: @Moroshka Попробуйте пожалуйста такой способ, немного отличается от того что вы хотели, но должно помочь

Comment: Да, такой сработает), но немного не то. Но все же спасибо :)

Comment: @Moroshka Спасибо за отметку :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поменять код функции `alls` от `@EzioMercer` на этот

(если проблема его совета именно в неправильной работе счётчика)

```
function alls(text){
  let updCount;

  setCount(prev => {
    updCount = prev + 1
    return updCount
  });

  return {
      text,
      id: updCount,
  }
}
```

Если не поможет, покажите полностью код, вместе с рендером

Comment: Интересное решение) Если ваш ответ будет принят, поясните и мне пожалуйста почему в моём случае что-то вообще зацикливается))

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-defrxx?file=index.tsx

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rku1fj?file=index.tsx

```
const App = () => {
  const initId = 100;

  const [items, setItems] = useState(createInitialItems());

  const [count, setCount] = useState(initId + items.length + 1);

  function createInitialItems() {
    return [
      createItem('one', initId + 1),
      createItem('then', initId + 2),
      createItem('this', initId + 3),
    ];
  }

  function createItem(text: string, id: number) {
    return {
      text,
      id,
      ret: false,
    };
  }

  function addItem(text: string, count: number) {
    setCount(count + 1);
    const newItem = createItem(text, count);
    setItems((items) => [...items, newItem]);
  };

  function renderItem(item) {
    return <span key={item.id}> {item.id} | </span>;
  }

  console.log(items);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <p>123</p>
      <button onClick={() => addItem('text', count)}>Click</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      {items.map(renderItem)}
    </div>
  );
};
```